# How can I perform click in web browser control?

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, button, webbrowser-control

I am trying to click a div id button in vb.net, I have the webbrowser included, here is my current code. I'm just trying to click the 'Do Job' on the website, but in vb.net.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hunt_job_button100").InvokeMember("click")
```

This doesn't work, the div id for the website is:
[image]
[image]

I also need to display a little text from the facebook app itself to a textbox in vb.net, and the div id for the text i want to copy to the vb.net textbox is "energy_value".

Everything on this app is div id

Comment: Wouldn't be better to invoke a javascript function?

Comment: How would I do this @T.S.? Could you give me a tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437251/calling-a-javascript-function-in-the-c-sharp-webbrowser-control

Comment: I actually needed it to click in the webbrowser control.

Comment: @T.S. could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hunt_job_button100").InvokeMember("click")
```

Or as you are using Class also i suggest to use it :

```
  HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
    foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
    {
        if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "hunt_job_button")
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click");
        }

}
```

regards

Comment: Thanks for your response! This didn't work, I tried this before, here is what I get: http://prntscr.com/5nmvia

Comment: I still didn't get this to work. I've tried everything and still nothing. Here is what I have: http://prntscr.com/5pdlmm

Comment: could you help me. Please look at previous comments. @Bouam

Comment: Hi , i'm taking a look !

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no control over the html or javascript on the page itself. The only thing I have control over is the clicking.